# Each ID with how many “column1”, “column2” and “total ” and order them by “total”

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following table in PostgreSQL 9.2:

```
CREATE TABLE leave
(
  "ID" text NOT NULL,
  "Leave class" text NOT NULL,
  "Leave Date" date NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT leave_pkey PRIMARY KEY (payroll, "Leave class", "Leave Date")
)
```

[image]

I want to get each ID with how many “Emergency”, “Sick” and “total leave” and order them by “total leave” (descending). Something like this:
[image]

Comment: the desired result is not clear with the showed input : 23266 has only one sick leave, no ? and 23234 has one sick leave and one emergency leave.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, I made mistake in the last table sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that (not clear if you use ID or Payroll)

```
select Payroll,
       sum(case when "Leave class" = 'Emergency' then 1 else 0 end) as "emergency leave",
       sum(case when "Leave class" = 'Sick' then 1 else 0 end) as "Sick leave",
       count(*) as "Total"
FROM leave
group by Payroll
order by count(*) desc;
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/a8769/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will show zero counts too: which matter if you want to take payroll values from another table

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/066de/1 for more

```
SELECT
  base.payroll,
  leaveCounts.Emergency,
  leaveCounts.Sick,
  leaveCounts.Total
FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT payroll FROM leave) AS base
  LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT
     COUNT(CASE WHEN "Leave class" = 'Emergency' THEN 1 END) AS Emergency, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN "Leave class" = 'Sick' THEN 1 END) AS Sick,
     COUNT(*) AS Total,
     payroll
  FROM
      leave
  GROUP BY
     payroll
  ) AS leaveCounts
      ON base.payroll = leaveCOunts.payroll
ORDER BY
  leaveCOunts.Total DESC;
```

The simpler code is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/066de/3

```
SELECT
     payroll,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN "Leave class" = 'Emergency' THEN 1 END) AS Emergency, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN "Leave class" = 'Sick' THEN 1 END) AS Sick,
     COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM
      leave
  GROUP BY
      payroll
   ORDER BY
     COUNT(*) DESC;
```